# tinyMCE caret positioning while moving in and out of span

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, caret

### Intro

I'm using tinyMCE to edit markup style syntax (TeX-like equations). To denote places where processing will be required after the content is submitted from tinyMCE, I am adding span elements to allow custom CSS to highlight the markup and attach id attributes to it. I'm having some difficulty getting sensible caret positioning behaviour when moving between the span and the enclosing paragraph - often the caret will skip a character when moving from the beginning of the span to outside the span.

### A concrete example

(I'm running Firefox 12 on a MacBook)

test.html: http://pastebin.com/m8nAmetz

CSS styling for eqn and inline classes: http://pastebin.com/cQVRGVMS

Pressing the right arrow with the caret positioned before the CSS rendered '$' into the span results in the caret moving to after the first m in 'moreinterestingeqnstuff', and the same process repeated after the second f in '...stuff' results in the caret skipping the first space after the span. Clicking to select caret position briefly positions the caret correctly, before it is pushed into one of the above error states.

### The questions

Have I done something wrong here? If not, does anyone know if this is a tinyMCE bug or a browser bug and if a workaround exists in either of these cases?

**Update:** OK, I guess I'll have to enter handling pseudo elements (see below) as a feature request with the tinyMCE folks. However, even without the pseudo-elements, I have an issue with the caret handling. In this fiddle http://fiddle.tinymce.com/EGbaab I have removed the inline class, which removes the before and after styling. If I want to insert a character directly after the span, I can't, as moving the caret to immediately after the last f in '...stuff' immediately places it inside the span.  Is there a way to disable this feature in tinyMCE, or alternatively what's the best way to implement this behaviour?

Comment: could you create a tinymce fiddle? (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/)

Comment: Sure: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sGbaab

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you have not done anything wrong here, but you need to know that the movement of the caret does not take care of css pseudo elements like after and before. They are used here. So this is obviuos not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have a (more subtle) positioning problem without the pseudo-elements though - see edit above.

Comment: What you describe is the default editor behaviour (in Word too). In order to change this behaviour you would have to implement this handling on your own in a tinymce plugin. But i strongly advise you not to do this, because it is pretty much work for a thing that is contryry to the default user experience. Addressing your first concern (the pseude-element problem): Even the tinymce folk won't be able to change this behaviour. The behaviour of this css setting is defined in standards and browsers implement those. There is no way to place a caret in a pseudo element!

Comment: There is a subtle difference to the behaviour in Word; if I have the text "b_old_ing" in Word, position the caret after the i and press backspace the i is deleted but the caret is not moved inside the italicised region, meaning if I type 'i' I recover the original text I have (e.g. the i is not italicised). In tinyMCE, if I position the caret after the space after the underlined div and press backspace, the caret is moved into the span, meaning there is no way to retype the space after the span.

Comment: Apologies, replace "underlined div" with "underlined span" :/